# Regex for a word can be plural

Tags: javascript, regex

I want regex that will match "lead" or "leads" and will not match when it's part of another word like cheerleaders or leaders. I also don't want whitespaces matched before or after the word.

The closet I got was `/(?:^|\W)Lead(?:$|\W){0,5}/g;`

But this matches Leaders and whitespaces. This is in javascript if that makes a difference.

Comment: is "lead" the only word or do you mean any word?

Comment: lead is the only word.

Comment: `\bleads?\b` is what you want then

Comment: [Not on my end](https://regex101.com/r/ilvs9G/1)

Comment: yep that works. go ahead and answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\bleads?\b` is all you need. `\b` is a word boundary, which means the word ends at the boundary.

`s?` is an optional s

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ilvs9G/1/)